# irreducible unitary reflection group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, reflection

Let $G$ be a finite irreducible unitary reflection group (i.e. without G-invariant subspaces). Given orthonomal basis, we have that $g_1 \in GL(V)$ commutes with every element of $G$. It is said that in this case $g_1$ necessarily be a scalar matrix as a consequence of Schur's lemma which (in particular) states that two G-invariant hermitian forms are similar up to coefficient $\lambda >0$. But I'm confused in binding these two facts together.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the field is algebraically closed. Let $c$ be an eigenvalue of $g_1$, the eigenspace $V_c$ is stable by $G$, thus it is $V$ since the action is irreducible.

Comment: for sure, it follows that $g_1$ has one eigenvector, but it doesn't mean $g_1 = \lambda I$, n'th dimensional jordan block will be also suitable.

Comment: @Anna: If $g_1$ is not diagonalizable, it still has a proper eigenspace which then has to be $G$-invariant.

Comment: @studiosus, $g_1$ has  no proper eigenspaces, but how to condlude from this that $g_1 = \lambda I$

Comment: It follows that the eigenspace $V_c=V$, so $g=cI$. To see this, let $x\in V_c, g\in G$, $g(g_1(x))=cg(x)=g_1(g(x))$, thus $g(x)\in V_c$ and $G$ preserves $V_c$, since $G$ is irreducible, $V=V_c$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide, let's take a simple example. $dim V=2$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1\;1 \\ 0\;1\end{pmatrix} \in GL(C)$. Isn't V an eigenspace for eigenvalue $1$?

Comment: is that eigenspace preserved by an irreducible action on $C^2$?

Comment: @TsemoAristide Nope, in this case $G$ has a $G$-invariant subspace $<\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}>$

Comment: @Anna: Over an algebraically closed field every linear transformation has an eigenspace.

Comment: @studiosu, thanks for response. I've just thought of an eigenspace as a root space in the first answer, so it gave rise to misconceptions, sorry.